# document.createElement('div') with a class

Tags: javascript, css

I can use createElement() to create an HTML element via JavaScript like this:

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
```

But how can I add a CSS class to my newly created div?

I tried something like this, but didn't work:

```
let div = document.createElement('div class=myDiv');
```

Comment: If your new `div` will be added to the DOM, you can also use HTML markup to describe it, and then `.insertAdjacentHTML` to create and add it. `var html = "<div class=myDiv></div>"; targetElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);` That method gives you 4 positions relative to the target to which you can added to the DOM. See the docs for more info.

Comment: This question still needs to be answered. It is not a duplicate of the proposed. This question is looking to add the classname in the same line. The duplicate is just looking to add a classname in general.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Do `div.classList.add`

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('test');
let text = document.createTextNode('Test');
div.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(div)
```

```css
.test {
  color: green;
}
```

You can also do by `className`

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'test';
let text = document.createTextNode('Test');
div.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(div)
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to set the attribut "className", usefull to add many classes:

`div.className = "class1 class2"`;

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Element.classList.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods)

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add("myDiv")
```