# Creating, populating, and appending a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an div in my HTML body titled recipeContainer. I am trying to use an API to search for recipes based on keywords from the user. Originally, I had 6 divs in an HTML that were populated in my javascript and styled in CSS, but that is no longer an efficient solution I think.

Here is my current code in the attempt to transfer functionality into each recipe's tile being created entirely in JS :

```
for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
    let div = document.createElement("div"+i);
    div.style.color = "gray";
    div.style.width = "200px";
    div.style.height = "350px";
    div.style.display = "flex";
    div.style.textAlign = "center";
    div.style.borderRadius = "15px";
    div.style.flexDirection = "column";
    document.getElementById("recipeContainer").appendChild(div);
}
```

This is the loop executed whenever a user hits submit. I actually have two questions pertaining to this, firstly, I expected this code to create 5 200px x 350px gray tiles in my recipeContainer div, but nothing appears. What am I missing?

Secondly, when it comes to appending info from my API call(such as recipe name, food image, etc.), how would I go about appending to my selected div? Could I just declare a variable(ex. foodImg) getting that information from my JSON data, and do `div.appendChild(foodImg)` , as well as contain all the styling of the element I'm trying to add, inside of the javascript?

Comment: first thing, `document.createElement("div"+i)` is not creating a valid HTML element.  May I know why are you appending `i` to "div"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [document.createElement('div') with a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55224589/document-createelementdiv-with-a-class)

Comment: Also, the styling should probably just be in CSS with a `.class` as a selector, then you only have to add `div.className = 'MyClass'`. Otherwise, it might also be better to, after receiving your data, use something like `div.innerHTML = \`<h2>${Title}\``, using a combo of innerHTML and template strings to populate your contents.

Comment: @Omkar76, I wanted to give each div a different ID, I think thats just leftover concepts from using 6 divs in my HTML. The answer provided clarified my confusion.

Comment: @somethinghere Thank you for the styling help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not creating a div at all since you are creating something with an html tag , and so on.

If you want to assign each div an id:

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("id", "Div"+1);
```

will do the trick.

See a fiddle:

```js
for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute("id", "Div1");
    div.style.color = "gray";
    div.style.width = "200px";
    div.style.height = "350px";
    div.style.display = "flex";
    div.style.textAlign = "center";
    div.style.borderRadius = "15px";
    div.style.flexDirection = "column";
    console.log(div);
    document.getElementById("recipeContainer").appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="recipeContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for informing me about setAttribute. If my understanding is correct, anything in .createElement besides the html would "break" it? So I use setAttribute instead to set id's and anything like that.

Comment: inside createElement you should put only the name of the html tag you are creating (div, p and so on). The attributes are to be added later in the code